# In Unreal Engine 5, how do I include and use UPlayMontageCallbackProxy::CreateProxyObjectForPlayMontage in C++?

Tags: c++, animation, unreal, unreal-5

I want to play my `UAnimMontage` via C++, and in particular, want to make use of the conveniences of `UPlayMontageCallbackProxy`.

Looks like in theory, I can use `UPlayMontageCallbackProxy::CreateProxyObjectForPlayMontage`, but anytime I use it, I just get linker errors:

```
0>YCharacterVaulting.cpp.obj: Error LNK2019 : unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl UPlayMontageCallbackProxy::PlayMontage(class USkeletalMeshComponent *,class UAnimMontage *,float,float,class FName)" (?PlayMontage@UPlayMontageCallbackProxy@@QEAAXPEAVUSkeletalMeshComponent@@PEAVUAnimMontage@@MMVFName@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl UYCharacterVaulting::Traverse(void)" (?Traverse@UYCharacterVaulting@@QEAAXXZ)
```

I’ve already updated my `Build.cs` so that the module is included:

```
PrivateDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] {"AnimGraphRuntime", "MotionWarping"});
```

Any ideas on how I can fix the linker error? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I never used the `UPlayMontageCallbackProxy` but `Error LNK2019` usually means you are lacking the include.

Looking at the [docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.3/en-US/API/Runtime/AnimGraphRuntime/UPlayMontageCallbackProxy/), you should add `#include "PlayMontageCallbackProxy.h"` to your file (as well as the `AnimGraphRuntime` Module that you already have in the `Build.cs`).

Is the include added to your file? If so, could you share the function you are using?